# InjectProcessingStep was unable to process 'CacheRepositoryImpl(androidx.datastore.core.DataStore<Settings>)' Hilt not working with proto datastore

Tags: android, android-jetpack, dagger-hilt, android-jetpack-datastore

InjectProcessingStep was unable to process 'CacheRepositoryImpl(androidx.datastore.core.DataStore)' because 'Settings' could not be resolved.
Dagger hilt not working with proto datastore genarated file.
My app was working fine until I tried implementing Proto DataStore and Hilt injection.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was.

- Update implementation  `com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:<version>` dependency to version `3.24.1`, should look like `implementation  "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.24.1"`
- also update `artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:<version>` version to `3.24.1` like

```
protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.24.1"
    }
}
```

- Finally update protobuf plugin `id "com.google.protobuf" version "<version>"` to `id "com.google.protobuf" version "0.9.4"`
- All of this changes should be in your module level gradle file the gradle file with `module:app`

More info check here https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/4024